# ExpressJS authorization middleware get executed even for the routes above it

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a university/student project with full MEAN stack. We have NodeJS, ExpressJS backend and Angular2 frontend. Backend runs on `localhost:8080` and frontend runs on `localhost:4200`

This is how my backend looks like

```
var express = require('express'),
...
var app = express();

...

// needed because of cross origin resource sharing during development
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var loginController = require('./controllers/loginController')(Person);
var personController = require('./controllers/personController')(Person, Transaction);
var transactionController = require('./controllers/transactionController')(Person, Transaction);

var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.post('/login', loginController.authenticate);

/**
 * Middleware that handles authorization of particular routes.
 * Every request which starts with `/api/persons` or `/api/transactions`, will be intercepted and validated against JWT.
 */
apiRouter.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // JWT gets validated
});

apiRouter.get('/persons', personController.fetchAllPersons);

apiRouter.get('/persons/:personId', personController.fetchPersonById);

apiRouter.get('/persons/:personId/transactions', personController.fetchTransactionsByPersonId);

apiRouter.post('/transactions', transactionController.addNewTransaction);

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

I read that the routes of the express router get executed sequentially, so the order of middleware inclusion is important. Therefore I set it after `/login` route since it should not be available without JWT authorization.
When I start the application and execute requests with `postman` everything works as it is supposed, but when I try to login from the frontend middleware function gets executed also for login route but it shouldn't, right?

Is is maybe because of they are running on different ports or could it be an issue caused by cross origin, I really have no idea?
Did anyone already face similar issue and could you please explain this behavior?
Thx

**EDIT 1:**

As robertklep has mentioned below, it might depend on the loginController implementation and the way how we handle login in frontend, here are the code snippets

```
jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var loginController = function (Person) {
    var authenticate = function (req, res) {
        req.person = req.body;
        var searchPerson = { username: req.person.username }
        Person.findOne(searchPerson, function (err, person) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (!person) {
                return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Wrong username/password' });
            }

            person.comparePasswords(req.person.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;

                if (!isMatch) {
                    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Wrong username/password' });
                }

                var token = jwt.sign(person._id, /* XXX SECRET XXX */);
                res.status(200).json({
                    token: token,
                    person: person
                });
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        authenticate: authenticate
    };
};

module.exports = loginController;
```

Frontend:

```
...
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 /**
   * validates input data and on successful validation,
   * tries to login the user with her/his credentials
   */
  public login(): void {
    // validation logic should consider all fields, no matter if the user has entered any data
    this.validate(false);
    // no validation error, continue with login process
    if(!this.errorMessage){
      const form = this.loginForm;
      var credentials = {
        name: form.get('name').value,
        password: form.get('password').value  
      };
      this.loginService.login(credentials.name,credentials.password)
      .subscribe(
        name => this.router.navigate(['welcome']),
        error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
  }
}

...
export class LoginService {
...
public login(userName: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
        var person = {
            'username': userName,
            'password': password
        };
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login',person)
            .map(this.extractToken)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As asked, I am posting my middleware, so this is how it looks like

```
apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // first, check if a token is provided
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
        // token gets validated by jwt lib
        jwt.verify(token, /* SECRET */, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                // token invalid, respond with unauthorized
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                });
            } else {
                // token is valid, continue to the particular request handler
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // token was not provided, respond with forbidden
        res.status(403).json({
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
});
```

Like I said, when I use postman client and execute login request, everything works as expected (Middleware doesn't execute for the login request) but when I start our frontend app and do the same, middleware function gets executed.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `loginController.authenticate`, and also how you're logging in from the front-end code.

Comment: Understand, so I've extended the issue description with loginController as well as login component from the frontend. Can you have a look at it please. Thx!

Comment: Actually, it looks okay to me. Is the `authenticate` function being called at all? Can you add `console.log(req.method, req.path)` inside the middleware to see for which request it's getting triggered? In fact, now that I think about it, it could be `OPTIONS /login` (CORS preflight)

Comment: How did you found out the middleware is running? Can you please elaborate like presenting code of middleware and logs by which you thought this usual behaviour.

Comment: @all, sorry for the late response. @robertklep, authenticate does not execute, because the token is not provided and yes the triggering request is `OPTIONS /login`. @Tolsee I am using visual studio code for debugging, so I've set a couple of break point and saw what gets triggered first. Have a look @EDIT2 for additional code snippets.

Comment: @amsalk you should probably look at [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to implement _proper_ CORS support. Either that, or have your own CORS middleware (which is setting the `Access-Control-*` headers) handle `OPTIONS` requests (which are [CORS preflight requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example)).

Comment: @robertklep you are right, since when I execute the same request from postman client the triggering request is `POST /login`. There is another workaround which looks also legit at least to me, extract middleware into it's own module and authorize every route individually. That has worked too. Thx for the help!